# Reading a PPM in C with fread() is returning only the first 5 values correctly

Tags: c, image, rgb, ppm

I am trying to create a program to read a .ppm file in C that reads the raw data and converts it to RGB values. My code works just fine up until the 5th pixel, then it just starts repeating the same output until EOF.

Here is my small code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  unsigned char r,g,b;
} pixel;

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

  FILE* fileOBJ;
  FILE* outFileOBJ;

  pixel currentPix;

  fileOBJ = fopen("pic.ppm","r");
  outFileOBJ = fopen("out.txt","w+");
  for (int i =0;i<(128*128);i++){
    fread(&currentPix, 3, 1, fileOBJ);
    fprintf(outFileOBJ,"%d.%d.%d ", currentPix.r, currentPix.g, currentPix.b);
  }

return 0;
}
```

and this actually works for the first 5 pixels outputting `0.4.4 0.4.4 0.4.4 0.5.5 0.6.6`

but then after that, it just spits out a few wrong values and then repeats `0.33.90 0.33.90` forever.

Does anyone have any clue what I am doing wrong?

The image is a P6 500x500, but I removed the header for simplicity. [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sqsvq9-oSXJWJxZU3wO6tROIUEeN_s8_/view?usp=sharing) is the file.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code, but some error-checking would help eliminate some possibilities.  If ```fread()``` fails you will never know it, and the content of ```pixel``` will never change.  Any return value not equal to 3 will indicate something has gone awry;  use ```ferror()``` to determine what.

Comment: @dave-not-cutler I added `if(ferror(fileOBJ)){
        printf("THERE WAS AN ERROR");
    }`

after my fread() and it's not printing anything.

Comment: I'd still check the return value.  Either it's 3 or something unexpected is happening.

Comment: I couldn't open the ppm file with a ppm viewer. Are you are sure the file is okay?